Tweaks->Appearance presents no themes 24.04.1 LTS

This version of Tweaks was very impoverished as contrasted with what I expected:

System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-28 07:31:04

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. PRIME X570-P
Memory:                                      96.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900X × 24
Graphics:                                    NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3070 Ti
Disk Capacity:                               4.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            4002
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic


you need to install gnome-themes-ubuntu to access additional themes see this Linux Packages article for more details

Thanks but Tweaks is not changed by installing gnome-themes-ubuntu.  There must be another step.

Admission to the arcane halls of Tweaks, one must add a number of other packages called "extensions" -- not just gnome-themes-ubuntu.  For example, after installing:
sudo apt install gnome-themes-ubuntu gnome-shell-extensions gnome-themes-extra gnome-shell-extension-manager

... one can find a mysterious option called "Shell":
Tweaks -> Appearance -> Styles -> Shell

Under this is a dropdown.  Although it doesn't tell you -- these items are the names of various "themes".
